# iOS Thread 1 signal SIGABRT Error

Tags: ios, xcode8, sigabrt

I am getting the "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT Error" in my code.  I have tried to reload my code into a different XCode project, inserting the like of code into a try/catch block, cleaning and rebuilding the project, tried checking some of my connections on the storyboard and I still can get anything resolved here.

Here is the source code of the main.m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SFAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
@try {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SFAppDelegate class]));
} 
@catch (NSException *e) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", e);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [e callStackSymbols]);
}
}
}
```

The error is showing up on this line of code:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([SFAppDelegate class]));
```

The XCode console is showing the following errors:

```
*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation   0x000000010a032d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171

1   libobjc.A.dylib   0x000000010967321e objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation   0x000000010a0a2f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132

3   CoreFoundation   0x0000000109fb8005 ___forwarding___ + 1013

4   CoreFoundation   0x0000000109fb7b88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120

5   ExApp   0x00000001060f954b -[Exercise getQuizResponseUrl] + 43

6   ExApp   0x0000000106117550 -[SFPreviewVideoView configureWithThumbnailProvider:duration:videoURLString:] + 816

7   ExApp   0x00000001061171bd -[SFPreviewVideoView configureWithThumbnailProvider:videoURLString:duration:delegate:] + 157

8   ExApp   0x00000001060cab6d -[SFQuestionsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1869

9   UIKit   0x0000000107a7e584 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757

10  UIKit   0x0000000107a7e7e2 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74

11  UIKit   0x0000000107a522b0 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295

12  UIKit   0x0000000107a87b64 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110

13  UIKit   0x0000000107a6e3be -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222

14  UIKit   0x00000001079d5ab8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237

15  QuartzCore   0x0000000107602bf8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146

16  QuartzCore   0x00000001075f6440 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366

17  UIKit   0x00000001079c3928 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1509

18  ExApp   0x00000001060dd0b3 -[SFBrandingTableFooterView updateBrandingView:forTableView:updatelayout:] + 147

19  ExApp   0x00000001060dcd5e -[SFBrandingTableFooterView showBrandingFooterViewAndUpdateLayout:animated:] + 446

20  ExApp   0x00000001060ca0a4 __46-[SFQuestionsViewController refreshDataSource]_block_invoke.147 + 964

21  ExApp   0x00000001060d3c79 __41-[SFBrain requestObject:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_3 + 105

22  libdispatch.dylib   0x000000010b508978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12

23  libdispatch.dylib   0x000000010b5320cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8

24  libdispatch.dylib   0x000000010b5128a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406

25  CoreFoundation   0x0000000109ff6e49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9

26  CoreFoundation   0x0000000109fbc37d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205

27  CoreFoundation   0x0000000109fbb884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420

28  GraphicsServices   0x000000010dfbfa6f GSEventRunModal + 161

29  UIKit   0x0000000107910c68 UIApplicationMain + 159

30  ExApp   0x00000001060c532e main + 142

31  libdyld.dylib   0x000000010b57e68d start + 1

32  ???   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you are showing, and the console errors don't match up either.

Comment: Do you see any other lines ontop of the `First throw call stack`?

Comment: Yeah here they are :

Comment: 2016-12-31 18:34:22.797 ExApp[26503:1590552] Branding footer Y offset = 243.333332

2016-12-31 18:34:23.005 ExApp[26503:1590552] -[Exercise viewQuizResponseUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800029bc10

2016-12-31 18:34:23.016 ExApp[26503:1590552] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Exercise viewQuizResponseUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800029bc10'

Comment: There is quite a bit more than that, but this is what I could post.

Comment: try to check the "#selector", it seems wrong format.

Comment: How do I check the "#selector"?  Where do I go to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Either your code is not implemented `[Exercise viewQuizResponseUrl]` or `[Exercise getQuizResponseUrl]`.. just check Exercise object is valid initialized or above methods are valid spell.